# Kubernetes python client change name of ConfigMap

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have the following deployment spec:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-web
          configMap:
            name: config-web-2-5
```

I want to use the kubernetes python client to change the name of ConfigMap from config-web-2-5 to config-web-3-0

```
def kubernetes_update_cm():
    v1 = client.AppsV1beta1Api()
    body = [{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/template/spec/volumes/0/config_map/name", "value": "config-web-3-0"}]
    ret = v1.patch_namespaced_deployment(name="my-app", namespace="default", body=body)
    return ret
```

However, the client returns the following error:

```
"message":"jsonpatch replace operation does not apply: doc is missing path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/config_map/name"
```

From the client src, I can see that this error occurs when the path isn't found in the deployment object.

Is this the correct path to use? There is only 1 volume in the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The path is not correct.

Correct path is:

```
/spec/template/spec/volumes/0/configMap/name
```

not

```
/spec/template/spec/volumes/0/config_map/name
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/358415)

Comment: The question was "Is this the correct path to use?". I provided the correct path as the answer.